# Why are the red cells moving? javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this assingment for school where there is a hidden cell in the table and you will have to try and find it. My problem is that the squares that are incorrect (red) move when another cell is clicked that is in the same row. I want it to stay red if the cell is incorrect and not move. I do not know why this is happening. Here is my code if you would like to look at it.

```js
Table.style.display = "none";
MainMenu.style.display = "block";
var name = '';

function Start() {
  Table.style.display = "block"
  MainMenu.style.display = "none"
  document.getElementById('playerName').innerHTML = 'Welcome ' + name;

}
var input = document.getElementById("text1");
input.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
  if (event.key === "Enter") {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("submit").click();
  }
});








function tableText(col) {
  if (typeof event !== 'undefined')
    el = event.srcElement
  for (var i = 0; i < el.parentNode.cells.length; i++)
    el.parentNode.cells[i].style.backgroundColor = ''
  el.style.backgroundColor = col
}


let colIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + 1;
let rowIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + 1;
console.log('col:' + ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'][colIndex - 1], 'row:' + rowIndex);
document.querySelector('#R' + rowIndex + 'C' + colIndex).onclick = () => {
  tableText('green');
}

function hideAll() {
  Table.style.display = "none"
  MainMenu.style.display = "block"
}


function gameReset() {

}

function required(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var empt = document.forms["form1"]["text1"].value;
  if (empt == "") {
    alert("Please input your name");
  } else {
    name = document.getElementById('text1').value;
    Start()
  }


}
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 0px solid white;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 45%;
  height: 55px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: center;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table.center {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.Tableheader {
  border: 0px solid white
}

.TableCell {
  background-color: rgb(252, 142, 215);
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.button {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #dcdcdc;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  color: #000;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

button:hover {
  color: yellow;
}

.TableCell:hover {
  background-color: rgb(255, 230, 0);
}

body {
  background-image: url('https://storage.pixteller.com/designs/designs-images/2019-03-27/05/simple-background-backgrounds-passion-simple-1-5c9b95bd34713.png');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">



<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <title>Document</title>

</head>



</body>
<div id="MainMenu">
  <form name="form1" action="#" onsubmit="required(event)">
    <ul>
      <h2>Hurkles the Game</h2>
      <p>Type in your name and click start to begin</p>
      <li><input type='text' name='text1' id='text1' /></li>
      <li class="rq">*Required Field</li>
      <li><input type="submit" name="submit" id='submit' value="Submit" /></li>
    </ul>
  </form>
</div>

<div id="Table">
  <div id='playerName'></div>
  <h2>Hurkles</h2>
  <p> Click a Cell to Find Hurkles</p>
  <table>

    <table id="tableID" class="center">

      <tr>
        <td id="R0C0" class="Tableheader"></td>
        <td id="R0C1" class="Tableheader">A</td>
        <td id="R0C2" class="Tableheader">B</td>
        <td id="R0C3" class="Tableheader">C</td>
        <td id="R0C4" class="Tableheader">D</td>
        <td id="R0C5" class="Tableheader">E</td>
        <td id="R0C6" class="Tableheader">F</td>
        <td id="R0C7" class="Tableheader">G</td>
        <td id="R0C8" class="Tableheader">H</td>
        <td id="R0C9" class="Tableheader">I</td>
        <td id="R0C10" class="Tableheader">J</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td id="R1C0" class="Tableheader">1</td>
        <td id="R1C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R1C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R1C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R1C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R1C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R1C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R1C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R1C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R1C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R1C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td id="R2C0" class="Tableheader">2</td>
        <td id="R2C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R2C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R2C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R2C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R2C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R2C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R2C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R2C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R2C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R2C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td id="R3C0" class="Tableheader">3</td>
        <td id="R3C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R3C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R3C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R3C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R3C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R3C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R3C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R3C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R3C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R3C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td id="R4C0" class="Tableheader">4</td>
        <td id="R4C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R4C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R4C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R4C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R4C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R4C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R4C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R4C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R4C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R4C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td id="R5C0" class="Tableheader">5</td>
        <td id="R5C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R5C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R5C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R5C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R5C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R5C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R5C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R5C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R5C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R5C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td id="R6C0" class="Tableheader">6</td>
        <td id="R6C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R6C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R6C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R6C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R6C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R6C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R6C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R6C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R6C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R6C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td id="R7C0" class="Tableheader">7</td>
        <td id="R7C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R7C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R7C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R7C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R7C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R7C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R7C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R7C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R7C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R7C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td id="R8C0" class="Tableheader">8</td>
        <td id="R8C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R8C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R8C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R8C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R8C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R8C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R8C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R8C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R8C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R8C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td id="R9C0" class="Tableheader">9</td>
        <td id="R9C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R9C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R9C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R9C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R9C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R9C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R9C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R9C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R9C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R9C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td id="R10C0" class="Tableheader">10</td>
        <td id="R10C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R10C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R10C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R10C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R10C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R10C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R10C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R10C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R10C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R10C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>

      </tr>


    </table>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button type="button" id="reset" onclick="hideAll()">Start</button>
</div>

</html>

</script>
```

Comment: You have a closing `</body>` instead of an opening one. You also have an extra script tag at the end. Please tidy your code up, remove all the blank lines, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you used this code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < el.parentNode.cells.length; i++)
  el.parentNode.cells[i].style.backgroundColor = ''
```

This code goes through every item in the row. Just remove it and then it will work!

```js
Table.style.display = "none";
MainMenu.style.display = "block";
var name = '';

function Start() {
  Table.style.display = "block"
  MainMenu.style.display = "none"
  document.getElementById('playerName').innerHTML = 'Welcome ' + name;

}
var input = document.getElementById("text1");
input.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
  if (event.key === "Enter") {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("submit").click();
  }
});








function tableText(col) {
  if (typeof event !== 'undefined')
    el = event.srcElement
  el.style.backgroundColor = col
}


let colIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + 1;
let rowIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + 1;
console.log('col:' + ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'][colIndex - 1], 'row:' + rowIndex);
document.querySelector('#R' + rowIndex + 'C' + colIndex).onclick = () => {
  tableText('green');
}

function hideAll() {
  Table.style.display = "none"
  MainMenu.style.display = "block"
}


function gameReset() {

}

function required(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var empt = document.forms["form1"]["text1"].value;
  if (empt == "") {
    alert("Please input your name");
  } else {
    name = document.getElementById('text1').value;
    Start()
  }


}
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 0px solid white;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 45%;
  height: 55px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: center;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table.center {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.Tableheader {
  border: 0px solid white
}

.TableCell {
  background-color: rgb(252, 142, 215);
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.button {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #dcdcdc;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  color: #000;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

button:hover {
  color: yellow;
}

.TableCell:hover {
  background-color: rgb(255, 230, 0);
}

body {
  background-image: url('https://storage.pixteller.com/designs/designs-images/2019-03-27/05/simple-background-backgrounds-passion-simple-1-5c9b95bd34713.png');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">



<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <title>Document</title>

</head>



<body>
<div id="MainMenu">
  <form name="form1" action="#" onsubmit="required(event)">
    <ul>
      <h2>Hurkles the Game</h2>
      <p>Type in your name and click start to begin</p>
      <li><input type='text' name='text1' id='text1' /></li>
      <li class="rq">*Required Field</li>
      <li><input type="submit" name="submit" id='submit' value="Submit" /></li>
    </ul>
  </form>
</div>

<div id="Table">
  <div id='playerName'></div>
  <h2>Hurkles</h2>
  <p> Click a Cell to Find Hurkles</p>
  <table>

    <table id="tableID" class="center">

      <tr>
        <td id="R0C0" class="Tableheader"></td>
        <td id="R0C1" class="Tableheader">A</td>
        <td id="R0C2" class="Tableheader">B</td>
        <td id="R0C3" class="Tableheader">C</td>
        <td id="R0C4" class="Tableheader">D</td>
        <td id="R0C5" class="Tableheader">E</td>
        <td id="R0C6" class="Tableheader">F</td>
        <td id="R0C7" class="Tableheader">G</td>
        <td id="R0C8" class="Tableheader">H</td>
        <td id="R0C9" class="Tableheader">I</td>
        <td id="R0C10" class="Tableheader">J</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td id="R1C0" class="Tableheader">1</td>
        <td id="R1C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R1C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R1C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R1C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R1C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R1C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R1C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R1C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R1C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R1C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td id="R2C0" class="Tableheader">2</td>
        <td id="R2C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R2C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R2C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R2C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R2C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R2C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R2C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R2C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R2C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R2C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td id="R3C0" class="Tableheader">3</td>
        <td id="R3C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R3C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R3C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R3C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R3C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R3C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R3C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R3C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R3C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R3C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td id="R4C0" class="Tableheader">4</td>
        <td id="R4C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R4C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R4C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R4C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R4C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R4C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R4C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R4C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R4C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R4C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td id="R5C0" class="Tableheader">5</td>
        <td id="R5C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R5C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R5C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R5C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R5C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R5C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R5C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R5C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R5C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R5C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td id="R6C0" class="Tableheader">6</td>
        <td id="R6C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R6C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R6C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R6C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R6C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R6C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R6C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R6C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R6C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R6C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td id="R7C0" class="Tableheader">7</td>
        <td id="R7C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R7C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R7C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R7C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R7C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R7C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R7C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R7C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R7C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R7C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td id="R8C0" class="Tableheader">8</td>
        <td id="R8C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R8C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R8C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R8C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R8C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R8C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R8C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R8C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R8C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R8C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td id="R9C0" class="Tableheader">9</td>
        <td id="R9C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R9C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R9C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R9C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R9C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R9C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R9C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R9C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R9C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R9C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td id="R10C0" class="Tableheader">10</td>
        <td id="R10C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R10C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R10C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R10C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R10C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R10C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R10C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R10C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R10C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R10C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>

      </tr>


    </table>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button type="button" id="reset" onclick="hideAll()">Start</button>
</div>

</html>

</script>
```